# Append to exec-path the absolute file names of directories that match a regexp?

Tags: directories, exec-path

As explained [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath), by

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/sw/bin")))
```

one can append the directory name `/sw/bin` to  `exec-path`.

Is it possible to append to `exec-path` the absolute file names of all directories on *the local machine* that match a certain regular expression? (for example to append (full) directory names that begin with some string to `exec-path`)?

Comment: The directories where emacs should look for executables. Every directory has a path. Of course all directories on the local machine.

Comment: It doesn't give you the full power of regexps, but you might consider using `file-expand-wildcards`.

Comment: @npostavs what is the correct syntax to use `file-expand-wildcards` in this situation? I tried something `(setq exec-path (append exec-path '(file-expand-wildcards "C:/*/SeaMonkey")))` without success. If you are comfortable please consider to convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: don't quote the call. `(setq exec-path (append exec-path (file-expand-wildcards "C:/*/SeaMonkey")))`. I don't see a need to make a new answer for every possible function that can produce a list of directories.

Comment: @npostavs I confirm that this now works. Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Load library [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([`dired+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)).
2. Use this command:

```el
;; Change ROOT definition if you want a different Windows drive as root.
;; (Windows does not have a single root.)
(defun foo (regexp)
  "Append the accessible directories that match REGEXP to `exec-path'.
You are prompted for the REGEXP."
  (interactive (list (read-regexp "Regexp: ")))
  (message "Gathering directories...")
  (let* ((root         (if (eq system-type 'windows-nt) "C:/" "/"))
         (dirs-to-add  (diredp-directories-within
                         root
                         nil
                         (lambda (dir) (string-match-p regexp dir)))))
    (setq exec-path  (append exec-path dirs-to-add))))
```

---

FYI, this is `diredp-directories-within`, but the definition of `diredp-files-within` is too long to show here.  See [`dired+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el) for it.

```el
(defun diredp-directories-within (&optional directory no-symlinks-p predicate)
  "List of accessible directories within DIRECTORY.
Directories in `icicle-ignored-directories' are skipped, if you use
Icicles.  Otherwise, directories in `vc-directory-exclusion-list' are
skipped.

Optional arg DIRECTORY defaults to the value of `default-directory'.
Non-nil optional arg NO-SYMLINKS-P means do not follow symbolic links.
Non-nil optional arg PREDICATE must be a function that accepts a
 file-name argument.  Only directories that satisfy PREDICATE are
 included in the result."
  (unless directory (setq directory  default-directory))
  (let ((dirs  (diredp-files-within (directory-files directory 'FULL diredp-re-no-dot)
                                    () no-symlinks-p 'INCLUDE-DIRS-P
                                    #'file-directory-p)))
    (if predicate (diredp-remove-if-not predicate dirs) dirs)))
```

---

FYI2: See also [Emacs bug #21346](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21346), which I just reported.  It might affect the use of this command.

Comment: Actually I also get the error from the bug which you have reported (Opening directory: permission denied, C:/$RECYCLE.BIN/....). This is despite the fact that `C:/$RECY..` does not match my regexp.  Is there a way to bypass this error? (Emacs version 24.5, Windows).

Comment: I imagine you saw Eli's reply in the bug thread, and my reply to him. You could try using `ignore-errors`. Or you could try filtering out that particular directory, but there might be others that are also problematic. When I get some time I'll try to see if I can finesse this properly in `diredp-directories-within`. There may be problems, including performance, with (ignoring errors while) actually trying to access each directory in order to test it for accessibility.